# Hold a view on ViewPager when we are on another page

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I want to hold my view on the first fragment, when i'm on the two other. It's always reset him.

Schema:

- ViewPager

  - MainFragment (FrameLayout who contains the fragment from the NavigationView)

    - Home
    - ...
    - Settings
  - ListChat
  - Chat

How can I hold a view when i'm change page ?

Comment: you want to freeze your ui when you are not viewing your fragment. ?

Comment: Not really, just don't reset the fragment, but the answer below is correct.

Comment: cool nice.. have a great day..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set pageoffset limit for viewpager which is lets say number of fragments in pager

```
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);`
```

Comment: this is a good way when the number of tabs are small and fixed

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter you can cache the fragment you want and return in

```
getItem(int position)
```